# Which segment register is used by default?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-segmentation

I am studying computer architecture from the Intel Manual. The thing that I understand is that the instructions that we give are logical addresses which consist of a segment selector and an offset.
It is basically `CS register<<4 + offset`. The `Segment Selector` maps to the **GDT** or **LDT** as given in the `TI` bit of the segment selector. GDT consists of `Segment Descriptors` which have `BASE`, `LIMIT` and `RPL` and the output is base address. This `base address` + `offset` provides the `logical address`.

What are the rules that decide which segment register (`SS`, `DS`, etc.) applies to different memory operations?  e.g. what determines which segment is used for `mov eax, [edi]`?

Comment: Your question is not clear t me, can you explain a bit?

Comment: basically i want to know that how that data segment, stack segment gets assigned for a procedure.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785991/can-someone-help-me-with-segmentation-and-8086-intels-microprocessor

Comment: It explains that the segments are 64kb and can overlap in a linear address space but does not explain the process!

Comment: I edited your question to clearly ask what I *think* you were trying to ask, but I may have guessed wrong.  Please edit if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Code fetch always uses `CS`.

Data addressing modes default to `DS` (or `SS` when EBP or ESP are the base register) in "normal" addressing modes.  (e.g. `mov eax, [edi]` is equivalent to `[ds:edi]`, `mov eax, [ebp+edi*4]` is equivalent to `mov eax, [ss: ebp + edi*4]`).

(Some disassemblers make the segment explicit even when it's the default, so you see a lot of `DS:` cluttering up the disassembly output.  (You can use a segment override prefix to select which segment will apply to the memory operand in an instruction.)  In NASM syntax, explicitly using a `[ds:edi]` addressing mode will result in a redundant `ds` prefix in the machine code.)

Some instructions with implicit memory operands have different defaults:

Some string instructions use `ES:EDI` implicitly.  e.g. The [`movs` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html) reads from `[DS:ESI]` and writes to `[ES:EDI]`, making it easy to copy between segments without segment override prefixes.

Memory operands using `esp` or `ebp` as the base register default to `SS`, and so do the implicit accesses for stack instructions like [`push`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html)/`pop`/`call`/`ret`.

`FS` and `GS` are never the default, so they can be used for special purposes (like thread-local storage) in a flat memory model system like modern 32 and 64-bit OSes.

[wikipedia explains the same thing here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation#Practices).

---

This is also documented officially in [Intel's ISA manuals](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).  e.g. in Volume 2 (the instruction-set ref), *Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte* has a footnote saying:

> The default segment register is SS for the effective addresses containing a BP index, DS for other effective addresses.

(note that SP isn't a valid base address for 16-bit addressing modes.
Also note that when they say "index", that means when BP is used at all, even for `[bp + si]` or `[bp+di]`.  In 32 and 64-bit addressing modes, there is a clearer distinction between base and index, and `[symbol + ebp*4]` still implies DS as the segment because EBP is used as an index, *not* the base.)

There's no equivalent footnote for 32 or 64-bit addressing modes, so the details must be in another volume of the manual.

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for more links.

Comment: where do these segments reside in memory? Linear address? Physical address?

Comment: @ashish: In current 32-bit OSes, all the segments (except FS and GS) have base=0, limit=4GiB, giving a flat memory space where `CS`, `DS`, `SS`, and `ES` are all equivalent.  Segment translation happens before virtual-to-physical address translation.  In Real mode, segment registers don't index descriptors, they're just multiplied by 16 and added to the offset part of the address.

Comment: And in long mode i.e., x86_64 mode?

Comment: @ashish: IIRC, segments other than FS and GS can't even have non-zero bases in long mode.  AMD simplified / neutered them a lot for AMD64, since 32-bit OSes didn't use the functionality.  Only Multics fans were disappointed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810340/224132

Comment: that link answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterCordes where can I read about the values that CS, DS, SS, and ES are set to? What specifies that they're all set to base=0, limit=4gib?

Comment: @OmarDarwish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation#Practices / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model